# PDO Erreur : SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation

Tags: postgresql, pdo, prepared-statement

postgresql:

```
create table t(c real);
```

PHP PDO :

```
$sql= 'insert into t (c) values (:c)';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare ( $sql );
$stmt->bindParam ( ':c',-0.06 );
$stmt->execute ();
```

output

```
Erreur : SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "-0.06 "
```

Comment: are you using postgres? it would be quite a good idea to tag your question with this database.

Comment: BTW, googling for the error message text would be even better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm....

you can't insert -0.06 into an integer field.  Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE t ALTER COLUMN c TYPE numeric;
```

Then it should just work.  Numeric types are safe for currency use because they losslessly convert to/from base 10, unlike floating points (I am assuming that this is financial given that the type is integer and the precision is to 1/100.